# Specify Color for autoref Without Affecting Other Document Links

Tags: hyperref, color, autoref

I am creating a document to be used by people not familiar with TeX.  I am using the autoref command throughout the document to refer to tables, figures, etc.  I would like to clearly signal to my audience that these are clickable internal links by making the links a different color from the surrounding text.  By configuring the hyperref package options in the preamble, I can change the color of all of the links in my document.  E.g.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = black,
            citecolor = black,
            anchorcolor = black]{hyperref}
```

But, this also results in my footnotes, table of contents entries, etc. turning colors and that creates a confused, "busy," and unhelpful appearance to my document.  I would thus like a way to change only the color that appears for the links when I use the autoref command.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished by defining a new version of the autoref command that will have the desired formatting.  For example, in the preamble, add:

```
\newcommand\colorAutoref[1]{{\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}\autoref{#1}}}  %% allows for calls to \autoref{} that have a different color from other links.
```

Then, in the document, where you want to add your autorefs, just use:

```
As can be seen in \colorAutoref{fig:2} the presentation of this document is now more clear.
```

Comment: I got the idea for how to devise this answer from this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226370/having-several-different-colored-borders-for-internal-links?rq=1  I wished I could upvote the helpful answer, but I didn't have enough reputation on this SE platform.